# Getting data into dataGridView

Tags: c#, mysql, web-services

The problem is getting data in my dataGridView from my webservice. When i invoke the getList method from the webservice i get the right xml code.
This is my code:
web service:

```
[WebMethod]
    public DataSet getList()
    {
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection();
        connection.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;" +
                                   "Trusted_Connection=yes;" +
                                   "database=oving1; " +
                                   "connection timeout=30";
        string select = "select * from Person";
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(select, connection);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        da.Fill(ds, "Person");
        return (ds);
    }
```

form:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Service1 webService = new Service1();
        DataSet ds = webService.getList();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;


    }
```

Comment: Try filling the ds into a data table and then link this table to a grid view.

Comment: Is `ds` populated as expected? Use breakpoints.

Comment: try dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0], also make sure you don't have autogeneratedcolumns set to false for dataGridView1 in design

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You better check this [Avoiding DataSet in Web services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188755.aspx#S4)

To serialize Dataset over WebServices [Consuming a DataSet from an XML Web Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s5xy331f%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

One more thing try to deliver a datatable to grid not dataset :

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```

Comment: @Ravia , thanks, but stianboe has 13 points, he need 2 more points so he can vote ;)